# 400 Validation error when I try to post with swagger

Tags: javascript, swagger

I made a project with swagger only for testing swagger and I get a 400 bad When I try to post what is wrong??

I do not have any problem geting the data from the array.

```
{
    "message": "Validation errors",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "code": "REQUIRED",
                    "message": "Value is required but was not provided",
                    "path": [
                        "paths",
                        "/recipe",
                        "post",
                        "parameters",
                        "0"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "in": "body",
            "message": "Invalid parameter (body): Value is required but was not provided",
            "name": "body",
            "path": [
                "paths",
                "/recipe",
                "post",
                "parameters",
                "0"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

recipe.js file:

```
module.exports.createRecipe = (req, res) => {
  let newRecipe = req.body;
  newRecipe.id = recipeList.length;
  newRecipe.isPublic = true;
  recipeList.push(newRecipe);

  return res.status(204).end();
};
```

```
paths:
  /recipe:
    x-swagger-router-controller: repice
    get:
      description: Return all the recipes
      operationId: getAllRecipes
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success get all the recipes
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: "#/definitions/Recipe"
        500:
          description: Unexpected Error
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              messeage:
                type: string
    post:
      description: Create one new Recipe
      operationId: postRecipes
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: The recipe to be added
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Recipe"

      responses:
        204:
          description: Success adding the rescipe
        500:
          description: Unexpected Error
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              messeage:
                type: string
```

What Do I need to do to make it work???

What do I need to do to make

I expect a 204 request and the recipe will be added to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to learn how to use Swagger to document my code and I thought to learn from Node JS: API Development with Swagger in Udemy.com but I had a problem with getting the params from req.swagger.params.id.value for example and req.body

to fix the problem with the body I found out that you needed to add app.use(bodyParser.json()); in the app.js file but when I did this I could not the req.swagger.params.id.value to work.

```
    "use strict";

var dotenv = require("dotenv");
var app = require("connect")();
var http = require("http");
var swaggerTools = require("swagger-tools");
var swaggerUI = require("swagger-ui-express");
var serverPort = process.env.PORT || 10010;
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

dotenv.config();
var options = {
  controllers: "./api/controllers",
  useStubs: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? true : false, // Conditionally turn on stubs (mock mode)
};

var swaggerDoc = require("./api/swagger/swagger.json");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);
// Initialize the Swagger middleware
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
  // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
  app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

  // Validate Swagger requests
  app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator());

  // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
  app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(options));

  // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
  app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());

  app.use("/docs", swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDoc));

  // Start the server
  http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.log(
      "Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)",
      serverPort,
      serverPort
    );
  });
});
```

I started to look at this example to see how they have set up Swagger

https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/blob/master/examples/2.0/index.js

with this example, I can get both parameters.
But

And add this to make a page with the documentation for your AP:
app.use("/docs", swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDoc));

To get the response from the api remember you need to put the right address in postman and for example:

http://127.0.0.1:10010/v1/api/recipe

and in the controlles folder file .js you need to add this in the bottom of the methode
get method:

```
 res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 res.end(JSON.stringify(List));
```

create method:

```
 res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 res.statusCode =201; 
 res.end(JSON.stringify(newRecipe));
```

make a error:

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
res.statusCode = 404;
res.end(`Could not find the recipe with id: ${recipeId}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your swagger POST error 400 is a classic case of missing a required field in your request body. The message Value is required but was not provided is your clue here. Check your swagger definition for the `/recipe` POST operation and ensure all required fields are included in your request payload. This often happens when testing endpoints that expect specific data structures. Double-check your request against the swagger docs.